# Find the union and intersection of grouped variables

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have two vectors that are binned.
Basically, I want a function to find the union and intersection of these two vectors (output).
It seems there is no function that supports this feature. Any idea of how i can carry out the desired output vector?

```
example1 <- c("18--25", "26--30", "31--50", "51+")
example2 <- c("18--23", "24--30", "31--65", "66+")

output <- c("18--23", "24--25", "26--30", "31--50", "51--65", "66+")
```

Comment: I believe in order to extract the desired outputs the grous have to be converted into numbers by removing "--" and "+". If someone can build a function can you also incorporate the symbol that are the groups are discriminated ("--" and "+")

Comment: One helper might be: `strcapture("([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]*)", example1, list(a=1L, b=1L))`, producing a two-column frame with the ranges, and `NA` for the unbounded ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can remove duplicates and combine a sorted vector every 2 elements like this (R version 4.0 and later for pipe `|>`):

```
f <- function(x, y, sep, max){
  m <- paste0("\\", max)
  gsub(m, "", c(x, y)) |>
    strsplit(sep, fixed = T) |>
    unlist(use.names = F) |>
    sort() |>
    unique() |>
    as.numeric() |>
    (\(.) tapply(., gl(length(.), 2, length(.)), paste, collapse = sep, simplify = T))() |>
    (\(.) .[!is.na(.)])() |>
    as.character() |>
    (\(.) {.[length(.)] <- paste0(.[length(.)], max) ; .})()
}  

# for older R versions
f <- function(x, y, sep, max){
  x <- gsub(paste0("\\", max), "", c(x, y))
  x <- as.numeric(unique(sort(unlist(strsplit(x, sep, T), use.names = F))))
  x <- tapply(x, gl(length(x), 2L, length(x)), paste, collapse = sep, simplify = T)
  x <- as.character(x[!is.na(x)])
  x[length(x)] <- paste0(x[length(x)], max)
  x
}

f(example1, example2, "--", "+")
[1] "18--23" "24--25" "26--30" "31--50" "51--65" "66+"
```

Comment: It seems there are unexpected symbols

Comment: @Nicolas123 Not sure what that means - when you run the function it returns incorrect results? or throws an error?

Comment: Throws errors due to unexpected symbols. What does |> operator do?

Comment: Nicolas123, that's new to R-4.1. If you are using something before that, you can opt to replace `|>` with `%>%` instead since you're already using `dplyr`. If you were not using `dplyr`, then one might need `library(magrittr)` to get to `%>%`.

Comment: I have modified that but again it throws an error. Could you please post the equivalent answer for the previous version in R? I am using dplyr btw

Comment: Basically, the error occurs due to unexpected symbol \

Comment: Thank you so much man! I have to download the newest version of R also to learn the new cool stuff!